# Select some but not all child nodes

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have the following XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<articles>
  <article id="1">
    <title>Article title 001</title>
    <short>Short text</short>
    <long>Long text</long>
  </article>
  <article id="2">
    <title>Article title 002</title>
    <short>Short text</short>
    <long>Long text</long>
  </article>
</articles>
```

I want to select only `<title>` and `<short>`.

Currently using this to display everything:

```
 $queryResult = $xpathvar->query('//articles/article'); // works fine grabs all articles
 foreach($queryResult as $result){
   echo $result->textContent;
 }
```

The expected output would be:

Article title 001

Short text

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Working solution!

```
if ($artId == "") {
    $queryResult = $xpathvar->query('//articles/article/*'); // grab all children
    foreach($queryResult as $result){
      if($result->nodeName === 'title' || $result->nodeName === 'short') {
          echo $result->textContent;
      }
    }
}else{
    $queryResult = $xpathvar->query(sprintf('//articles/article[@id="%s"]/*', $artId)); // Show requested article
    foreach($queryResult as $result){
      if($result->nodeName === 'title' || $result->nodeName === 'long') {
          echo $result->textContent;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: What output would you actually like to see?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a much more efficient solution -- also a more "XPath-y" one. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
/articles/article/*[name()="title" or name()="short"]
```

which would only return children of any "articles/article" with an element name of "title" or "short".

---

As an alternative, change the XPath to `/articles/article/*` to fetch all childNodes of article and when iterating `$results` check if [`DOMNode::nodeName`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodename) is "title" or "short", e.g.

```
$queryResult = $xpathvar->query('/articles/article/*'); // grab all children
foreach($queryResult as $result){
  if($result->nodeName === 'title' || $result->nodeName === 'short') {
      echo $result->textContent;
  }
}
```

---

If you dont want to change the XPath, you have to iterate the [`childNodes`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.childnodes) of the article, e.g.

```
$queryResult = $xpathvar->query('/articles/article');
foreach($queryResult as $result) {
  foreach($result->childNodes as $child) {       
  if($child->nodeName === 'title' || $child->nodeName === 'short') {
      echo $child->textContent;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, Your first solution works, but... I also need to be able to select just one article based on ID and display Title and long text.

Comment: @StefWill The XPath would be `//articles/article[@id=1]/*[name()="title" or name()="long"]`. Have a look at this [Xpath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp)

Comment: +1 Good answer. But, please, don't start an expression with `//` operator when schema is well known.

Comment: @Alejando thanks, also for the edits. Actually, I just copied over the XPath and didnt bother about the inital part of it. I know you keep telling me that :) But does it make a difference whether one uses the direct path or the double slashes when the document is just as shown above? Or put different: at what document size or structure does it really start to have an impact?

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
/*/*/*[self::title or self::short]
```

or if the `title` and `short` children of a specific `article` with known `@id` (say '2') should be displayed:

```
/*/article[@id='2']/*[self::title or self::short]
```

**Always try to avoid using the `//` abbreviation** when this is possible (when the structure of the XML document is known).

Using `//` very often results in grossly-inefficient evaluation, because `//` causes the whole (sub) tree rooted in the current node to be searched.